# WCF Security Model

Tags: web-services, wcf, security, authentication, authorization

I am about designing WCF service and security part looks toughest bit. The service will have two end points: SOAP and REST and will use form authentication. After reading a lot about security I decided to create separate Token Based Security Service (TBSS) which will be behind the my original service and there will be ws-trust between TBSS and my service. When client call my service to authenticate, authentication request will be passed to TBSS and TBSS will authenticate(or not) user and will return token which will be expired after a while. On subsequent client call, original service will take token and pass the token to TBSS with Method name and TBSS will authorize user.

What are the benefits of this model in my opinion:

1. User will not be authenticated each subsequent call which is very expensive.
2. My original service will stay stateless and
   seamlessly scalable.
3. Security will be completely segregated from actual service.

Although everything looks ok for me I am still not feeling very confident as I haven't implemented this model before, so I don't know what kind of problems I will encounter even will I be able to complete this? I would be appreciated if you can share your opinion/experience/expertise.

Comment: Sounds like a nicely thought-out plan to me. We did something similar, but used an actual Login(sGUID) function that returns a time-sensitive SessionID used for authentication on subseqent visits by client devices (andriod, iPhone, laptop). Though each request must reauthenticate, our system is designed to limit hits to about 3-6 for each synchroniztion, so the cost isn't much. When you performance test, you'll find the WCF service is nearly impossible to stress - it's that fast. Instead, your database will be your chokepoint.

Comment: Thanks Brain for your great input, I will remember this when I think about the performance.